# Fullness of composition implies fullness of the second functor?

Tags: category-theory, functors

I encountered a statement left as an exerciser in a category theory textbook:

> Let F: *C*→*D* and G: *D*→*C* be functors. Prove that if G◦F is full, then G is full.

My confusion is should there be objects X and Y in *D*, which are out of the range of the object mapping of F, then
G(hom<sub>*D*</sub>(X, Y)) ≠ hom<sub>*C*</sub>(GX, GY)
can happen (which makes G not full), even when G◦F is full.

I can think of a counterexample:

[image: diagram]

**Update #1**: as I keep reading, it seems the author perhaps actually have in mind that

> If F◦G is full and F is faithful, then G is full.

Indeed, for any *f* in hom<sub>C</sub>(GX, GY), there's a *g* in hom<sub>D</sub>(X, Y) such that F◦G(*g*) = F(G(*g*)) = F(*f*). The faithfulness of F then implies G(*g*) = *f*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true in general. Counterexample: take $C=\mathbb{N}$ (monoid of naturals by multiplication), $D=\mathbb{N}\sqcup\mathbb{R}$ (coproduct of monoids), $F=i_1\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\sqcup\mathbb{R}$ (canonical inclusion of the coproduct), $G=I_{\mathbb{N}}\sqcup\Delta_{*}\colon\mathbb{N}\sqcup\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{N}$ (where $I_{\mathbb{N}}$ is the identity functor and $\Delta_{*}$ is the trivial functor). Then $G\circ F=I_{\mathbb{N}}$ (which is trivially full), but $G$ is not.

Comment: Thank you for the conclusion and the example (which is a bit beyond my current CT literacy). Can you please also take a look at the toy example i came up with (in the image description)? My intuition is that if the object mapping of the first functor (F) is not surjective, then the statement is gonna fail.

Comment: @Pteros Of course, your intuition is correct. You can take any two categories with one object instead of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, such that the first category has more than one morphism (to break fullness).  For example, $C=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $D=\mathbb{Z}_2\sqcup\mathbf{1}$. The coproduct $\sqcup$ is something like "union" of two distinct categories.

Comment: @Pteros $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the category with one object $*$ and two morphisms $id(*)$ and $f$, such that $f\circ f=f$; $\mathbf{1}$ is a trivial category with one object and one morphism.

Comment: Thank you! I've got a related question. Suppose F◦G and G◦F are both fully faithful. Does it follow that both F and G are fully faithful? (if yes, how to show that?)

Comment: To Oskar: I can now see the related claim is true. It suffices to show the claim in Update #1, the reasoning of which I hope is correct.

Comment: Excuse me @Oskar, can you give me the name of the category theory book where you found that exercise?

Comment: @Irene I came up with this example myself, but perhaps you can find some similar examples in CT literature. For a start, I recommend Mac Lane's CFWM and Borceux's "Handbook of categorical algebra", Vol.1